# Gibbs sampling truncation for contrastive divergence

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expectation, sampling, monte-carlo

I am following Yoshua Bengio's [Learning Deep Architectures for AI](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/TR1312.pdf) and at page 31 there is a phrase that confuses me.

Starting by lemma 7.1 in the same page:

> **Lemma 7.1.** *Consider the Gibbs chain $x_1 \rightarrow h_1 \rightarrow
>  x_2 \rightarrow h_2 ...$ starting at data point $x_1$. The
>   log-likelihood can be expanded as follows for any path of the chain:*
>
> $\log P(x_1) = \log P(x_t) + \sum\limits_{s=1}^{t-1} \log \frac{P(x_s|h_s)}{P(h_s|x_s)} +
>  \log \frac{P(h_s|x_{s+1})}{P(x_{s+1}|h_s)}$
>
> *and consequently, since this is true for any path:*
>
> $\log P(x_1) = E\left(\log P(x_t)\right) + \sum\limits_{s=1}^{t-1} E\left(\log
>  \frac{P(x_s|h_s)}{P(h_s|x_s)} + \log
>  \frac{P(h_s|x_{s+1})}{P(x_{s+1}|h_s)}\right)$
>
> *where the expectation is over the Markov chain, conditional on $x_1$.*

$P$ here is the distribution from which we want to sample. This is ok for me, the problem is what comes afterwards:

> In the limit $t \rightarrow \infty$, the last term is just the entropy
>   of distribution $P(x)$. **Note that the terms do not vanish as $t
>  \rightarrow \infty$**, so as such this expansion does not justify
>   truncating the series to approximate the log-likelihood.

The bold part is the weird one for me. I've made the following simplifications:

$E\left(\log \frac{P(x_s|h_s)}{P(h_s|x_s)} + \log \frac{P(h_s|x_{s+1})}{P(x_{s+1}|h_s)}\right)$

$= E\left(\log \left(\frac{P(x_s|h_s)}{P(h_s|x_s)} \frac{P(h_s|x_{s+1})}{P(x_{s+1}|h_s)}\right)\right)$

(by applying sums of logarithms property)

$= E\left(\log \frac{P(x_s)}{P(x_{s+1})}\right)$

(by "unconditioning" the probabilities)

$= E\left(\log P(x_s)\right) - E\left(\log P(x_{s+1})\right)$

(by reapplying logarithm's sum property in the opposite way and expectation's linearity)

As $s \rightarrow \infty$ the chain converges:

$E(\log P(x_s)) = E(\log P(x_{s+1}) ) = E(\log P(x))$

and the term inside summation becomes 0. So, isn't it vanishing? Have I done any mistakes in my equations or have I misinterpreted the document?

Some updates: I think I was misinterpreting the truncation. The objective here would be to approximate $\log P(x_1)$ by an early sample from the Gibbs chain, and this sampling takes the form of the expectation inside the summation. The problem is that the term $E\left(\log P(x_t)\right)$ does not vanish, but I still don't understand why we cannot estimate this term as well by a sample from the chain.